# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'points' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tkinter

I know this question has been asked before but I can't seem to find an answer. I keep getting an error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'points' referenced before assignment I try moving it and making it global inside the function but I keep getting the same error.

code:

```
points = 0


def game():
    root = tk.Tk()

    global points



    def contunie():
        contunie_label.pack_forget()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        questions_maker()
        label.pack_forget()

    def wrong():
        pass

    def right():
        global points
        while True:
            points += 1
            break
```

Comment: While there's presumably some way to make this work using `global`, you should probably make `game` an object so you don't need globals in the first place.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds noob-like but I'm new to programming so would you please tell me how to make it an object?

Comment: This code doesn't produce any errors when run.

Comment: this is not the my whole script

Comment: Is the posted code inside another function? Better post a [mre].

Comment: How are we supposed to diagnose code that we can't see, and an error message that is paraphrased?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an alternative to debugging `global`-induced bugs, put your game state in an object so that you can access the state via `self` from within the instance methods:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.points = 0
        # self.cont_label = ???
        # self.label = ???

    def cont(self):
        self.cont_label.pack_forget()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.questions_maker()
        self.label.pack_forget()

    def right(self):
        self.points += 1

    def questions_maker(self):
        # ???

game = Game()
# game.???()
```